# Pass two arrays(A,B) and a string such as an Id into a function to filter them 'A but B'?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

```
AbutB(ArrayA, ArrayB, string factor)
{
// factor == "id"

for(item in ArrayA == ArrayB.factor)
// exclude item from Array A
}

return arrayA;
```

Code above is pusedo.

I think that the logic kinda make sense but I'm not sure how to make
"ArrayB.factor" thing work.
I guess its called a string interpolation. How should I do it?

Thank you for help in advance!

Comment: This is called array subtraction, has nothing to do with interpolation. `let bFactors = b.map(item => item[factor]); return a.filter(item => !bFactors.includes(item[factor]))`

Comment: @EstusFlask just confirmed and it works